# On image hover show a div area with the form in it

Tags: html

I want that on hover of image, div box should appear and user can select a option from that div.

```
<a class="show_img3" href="frequenz?link=3" class="btn">
  <img style="padding-top: 8px;padding-bottom: 26px;" src="<?php echo bloginfo( 'template_url' );?> /img/bouquet/2.png">
  <span class="bqy_no">BRAUCHE MEHR</span></a>
<div class="hide_img3"><a href=#>2</a><br><a href="#">3</a></div>
```

My problem is that I am not able to select a option as it disappears if i try to hover.

here is the [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3qLx/)

I have updated the fiddle to be more accurate what is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/m3qLx/9/)

just placed a parent div and applied a extra class to it.

Your Html and css its very untidy and non-semantic please make it readeble.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this and it works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.show_img3').hover(function(){
        $('.hide_img3').show();
    });
    $('.close a').click(function(){
        $('.hide_img3').hide();
    });
});​
```

You have to click the X to hide it after it's open.

Updated it for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/m3qLx/7/

Answer (score 1):

Do it with jQuery instead. There you can easily say that once the user hovers over the link/image, the div stays.

Here is how it works:

```
$('.show_img3').mouseover(function(){
    $('.hide_img3').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/m3qLx/8/

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this using jQuery.
If I understood correctly, then div with class hide_img3 is invisible, but when I point on img which is in a tags, then div becomes visible, yes?
For that, You can use this code.

```
$('.show_img3').hover(function () {
    $('.hide_img3').fadeIn(1000);
}, function () {
    $('.hide_img3').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

"it disappears if i try to hover"

If you want to go with plain CSS, you need an underlying wrapper, that holds both, the anchor and the div. If the hover-state is applied to that wrapper, the box will stay open.